# Click element next to some element in java using appium

Tags: java, android, xpath, appium

[image: Off Button]

Refer Above image, I want to click on Off/On Button shown under MAP LEGEND. In this page, there are three Off/On buttons present here. So its confusing me how to click on it particular.

I am using UIautomator for inspecting the Android App. By using it, I don't see xpath avail here.

If anyone provide solution or xpath for it. It would be helpful to proceed

**Details:-**

1. Java
2. Appium
3. UIAutomator for Android in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by finding the index. Use this:

```
public void tap(int index){
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElementByID("PUT YOUR ID");
li.get(index).click();
}
```

I guess your index would be 1. This way to can tap on any off button as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

xpath=//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,"Show Legend")]/following-sibling::android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,"textOff")]

Comment: this is the xpath needed to find the desired result.